# Best and safest way to store 1 million rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, database

I'm creating a radio unlock web app which counts with 1 million codes. What would be the best option to store and access those codes? Some security tips? It's ok to store it directly on mySQL? (For it I need to make 20 x 50k codes insertions, as server returns 500 error for more). Is there any other way to store this quantity of data? Maybe json?

I hope I don't sound too noob. It's the first time I'm handling so much data.

Thank you.

Comment: Store in Mysql and make the insert with a PHP script. Why are the server returning 500 error? show what you tried

Comment: 1 million rows is a small data size for a database (of course it can depend on a row size). MySQL can store it quite easily.

Comment: "best" and "safest" are totally subjective terms and will depend heavily on your specific circumstances, requirements and constraints. We don't have enough info to make a recommendation or specify a design, and in any case that's not what this site is for. We don't give opinions or recommendations, and we don't do big system architecture designs. You should consult an architect (of the technical or software variety, obviously). But really as Radim says, your database isn't particularly big by modern standards, you shouldn't have that many issues in reality.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The server where I try to perform the insert returns 500 (internet connection lost or server connection lost). This happens when I try to insert more than 50k rows. I do this using the mysql console, in this way "insert into 'code' (id, code) values (NULL, '1234'), (NULL, '2839'), (NULL, '2342'), etc". Would it work better if I use a PHP script for the insert?

Comment: Ok. So you do actually have a specific issue. This was not clear at all from your entirely theory-based question. "500" sounds like a HTTP error, so it means something caused your webserver code to crash. The root cause _might_ be something to do with your database, but without knowing what the exact fault was we can't be sure. Check your server's logs, if it has any, or enable PHP error reporting and you'll see it in the HTTP response. P.S. PHP has dedicated libraries for interacting with mysql, there should be no need to automate the mysql console.

Comment: Although, you could also consider whether, for a bulk upload, a LOAD DATA mysql command might be better. It depends on the circumstances, we don't have enough info about what the code is doing, where you're getting the data from etc. Maybe show us your code and explain further, and we can help you sort out the PHP code. This appears to be not so much about how you _store_ the data (which appeared to be your question), but about how you're _processing_ it.